# FlexLayout 7.x.x.beta angular not working on angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-flex-layout

I got an issue with the installation of flex-layout on my angular project. After the installation nothing works.

flex-layout [7.0.0-beta.23]
angular [7.2.7]

[image: package.json]

[image: app.module]

The code i'm trying to execute :

```
<div fxLayout="row">
    <div>1. One</div> <div>2. Two</div> <div>3. Three</div> <div>4. Four</div>
  </div>
```

result :

[image: result]

Do you have an idea why is it not working ?

thanks

Comment: Try beta 19, I think it's the best right now

Comment: It's not working either..

Comment: Could you please create a Blitz? stackblitz.com

Comment: The problem comes from my app.module.ts who doesn't send my imports to my children routes.. I will investigate how to solve this but I don't think flex-layout was the initial problem.

Comment: You got to export the RouterModule from the ThemeModule, since I guess you're declaring routes in there. Otherwise you can add an import for FlexLayout in your ThemeModule (or whatever loads your routes)

Answer (score 0):

Change your FlexLayoutModule import to:

```
FlexLayoutModule.withConfig({
  useColumnBasisZero: false,
  addFlexToParent: false,
}),
```